# AFNetworking set image without extension

Tags: ios, afnetworking

There is a method in AFNetworking that can set image conveniently:

```
 - (void)setImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url 
   placeholderImage:(UIImage *)placeholderImage
```

but if the url image have no extension(like http://static.qyer.com/album/user/330/21/QkpVQBsHaA/670), there are some problems,sometimes the image can be displayed exactly some times it is not displayed.

I found a method

```
  [AFImageRequestOperation addAcceptableContentTypes:<#(NSSet *)contentTypes#>];
```

how should I set the contentTypes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you `curl` the URL provided, you can see the problem:

`curl -i -X HEAD http://static.qyer.com/album/user/330/21/QkpVQBsHaA/670`

`HTTP/1.0 200 OK

Server: nginx/1.0.11

Date: Fri, 29 Mar 2013 02:03:24 GMT

Content-Type: application/octer-stream

Last-Modified: Tue, 19 Mar 2013 09:40:23 GMT

ETag: "53430075-9814c-4d843e4fc6fc0"

Accept-Ranges: bytes

Content-Length: 622924

Powered-By-ChinaCache: MISS from 060531Q354

Powered-By-ChinaCache: MISS from 060532235y

Connection: close`

`Content-Type: application/octer-stream` (which is, strangely, a misspelling of `application/octet-stream`), is not a valid image mime type. If you have any control over the server, I would strongly recommend you fix this to send real mime types—for the sake of everyone accessing the CDN.

Otherwise, I would recommend you add `*/*` to the list of acceptable content types. This should accept anything thrown at it. You can also manually specify any content types you might expect the CDN to serve, including `application/octer-stream`.