# Loading an image using SDWebImage with no file extension

Tags: ios, uiimageview, file-extension, sdwebimage

So I'm using `SDWebImage` to load images asynchronously in my iOS `UITableView`. To do this I call:

```
[cell.itemImageView setImageWithURL:imageUrl placeholderImage:[UIImage imageName:@"placeholder.png"]];
```

Where `imageUrl` might be:

```
imageUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.org/image.png"];
```

This all works fine, however the server API I'm using will occasionally return an image without an image extension. In this case SDWebImage appears to not attempt to load the image. Is there anyway I can force it to download the image? I cannot just append `.png` to the image as this causes permissions issues where the image is hosted.

EDIT: I have just ran this on a example image currently hosted (the GUID is the filename):

```
curl -i -X HEAD http://example.org/images/98b67f6a-671c-482c-8e3b-0ade8bfa01be
```

And it returns with this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
x-amz-id-2: UGcGcyUuUfWBD2YrhmfoRq8oiXIwEkBJ9x4TdimLAcPc9Yim26tRRgjN/PVBak+S
x-amz-request-id: 513EDF3EB400DE6E
Date: Mon, 12 Aug 2013 16:03:08 GMT
Last-Modified: Thu, 13 Jun 2013 01:28:50 GMT
ETag: "96ca8a122a94c97eee83ef685c7e2e7b"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Type: image/jpg
Content-Length: 17631
Server: AmazonS3
```

Comment: Could be an issue with server side. Check [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15696166/afnetworking-set-image-without-extension) for similar issue

Comment: @Amar, I have edited the question with my curl response. Looks OK to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really an answer but to resolve this I ended up changing the server to save images with their extension.

Answer (score 0):

The content type returned by the server is currently `image/jpg`; it should be `image/jpeg` instead.